# error bundle exec spring rails c

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

When I write:

```
bundle exec spring rails c
```

I take this error:

```
ERROR -- : Couldn't cleanly terminate all actors in 10 seconds!
```

I'm using 5.0.0.1 version of Rails.

Is there someone to help me please?

Comment: Are you using celluloid?

Comment: yes do you can help me please?

Comment: I just posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove spring from your executables directory. If your project is named 'hello', then type

```
rm hello/bin/spring
```

This was documented on the [celluloid github page](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/issues/696)